# Edit value in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'd like to run a simple mysql command to update a number of rows as follows:

coursename="Test Golf Club"

would need to be updated to remove " Golf Club" (note whitespace)
so that it becomes "Test"

Can this be done in one command?

Comment: UPDATE \`table\` SET \`coursename\`="Test" WHERE \`coursename\`="Test Golf Club" ?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the simple SQL - of course I can do that for one row.

However, this needs to run on 1000 rows, which are all different.

Test Golf Club
Another Golf Club
Different Golf Club
One without that string
Final Golf Club

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, wasn't a very clear question.

Comment: @JamieAbbott, see another alternative solution in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
UPDATE someTable set coursename = 'Test' where coursename = 'Test Golf Club'
```

would do, but it's not very flexible.

Using `REPLACE()` and `LIKE` will give you

```
UPDATE someTable set coursename = replace(coursename, 'Golf Club', '')
  WHERE coursename LIKE '%Golf Club%';
```

Which should find 'Golf Club' and replace it with an empty string. The 'WHERE' clause is probably redundant.

Answer (score 1):

To remove all occurrences of the string `' Golf Club'` that occur in values of a particular column, you can use the MySQL `REPLACE()` function in an `UPDATE` statement.

```
UPDATE mytable SET coursename = REPLACE(coursename,' Golf Club','')
 WHERE coursename LIKE '% Golf Club%';
```

It's good idea to test the expression in a SELECT before you use it in an UPDATE, e.g.

```
SELECT coursename                          AS old_val
     , REPLACE(coursename,' Golf Club','') AS new_val
  FROM mytable
 WHERE coursename LIKE '% Golf Club%';
```

Then you can verify that this expression works as expected, and is what you want to use.

(Note that the REPLACE function replaces multiple occurrences within a string, not just the first.)

Answer (score 0):

update TableName set coursename ='Test' where coursename = 'Test Golf Club'

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

```
set @str = 'Test Golf Club';

UPDATE someTable set coursename = (select substring(@str,
                 (locate(' ',@str) + 1),
                 (length(@str) -
                        locate(' ',@str)))) where coursename = 'Test Golf Club'
```